# ReactJS dynamically adding onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I have a react functional component and I want to decide dynamically if I want to have an onClick handler on it, something like this:

```
const foo () => {
  let add_onClick = true;
  return (
    <div *(if add_onClick ==true then add an onClick event)*/>
  )
}
```

I think I can convert the component to a class, create a Ref for the component then add a click eventListener in componentDidMount, but is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you keep in mind that:

```
let Foo = props => <div onClick={props.onClick} />
```

is really the exact same thing as:

```
let Foo = props => React.createElement('div', { onClick: props.onClick })
```

then it should be easy to see how you can optionally pass props. In JSX you can do:

```
let Foo = props => 
  <div 
    {...(props.onClick ? { onClick: props.onClick } : {})}
  />
```

This is, of course, a little silly, in particular because you can always click on a div whether you handle it properly or not. A much better solution to your exact question would be to do something like:

```
let doNothing = {} => {}
let Foo = ({ onClick = doNothing }) => <div onClick={onClick} />
```

That way you if you forget to pass a click handler, you'll still handle it by default, but do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a bit confused, what's wrong with the first answer? It seems if no click handler was passed, then no onClick will be attached. Why do I need to attack onClick and make it do nothing instead?

Comment: Ahh they're both fine, but the syntax for doing it in JSX sucks, and also I think it's better to always handle events if an event *could* be handled. Think about attaching propTypes.. an `onClick` propType sounds like a `function` to me, not an enum of `undefined` and `function`, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. `onClick` will be null unless your value is true:

```
<div onClick={add_onClick && () => {console.log("You clicked me!");}}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this as well

```
const foo = () => {
  let add_onClick = true;
  return (
    <div { ...add_onClick && { onClick: () => {} } }/>
  )
}
```